# Variable Value cannot be assigned to another variable

Tags: php, html

HTML CODE HERE

Some error with the for loop in the php code

```
 <html>
 <head><title>Hello
  </title></head>
   <body>
     <form id="cool" name ="form" action ="hi.php">
      <input type ="text" name="m1" value="m1"/>
          </br><input type ="text" name="m2" value="m2">
          </br><input type ="text" name="m3" value="m3">
          </br><input type ="text" name="m4" value="m4">
          </br><input type ="text" name="m5" value="m5">
          <input type="submit" >
         </form>
         </body>
         </html>
```

This is the php code, it says undefined index at line 6 , here mem is getting value m1 ,m2,m3,m4, but extracting the value from mem is not working

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $mem = 'm' . $i;

    $m = $_POST[$mem];
    print " The member is" . $m . "</br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you to specify the HTML form code.

Comment: add method="post" in your form tag

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `method="POST"` in your form tag

```
 <form id="cool" name ="form" action ="hi.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't noticed that :)

Answer (score 2):

use this   `<form id="cool" name ="form" action ="hi.php" method="post">`

instead
`<form id="cool" name ="form" action ="hi.php">`